# How does the following evaluate?

Tags: recurrence-relations

We have a recurrence as follows:

> $$T(n) = 2T\left(\sqrt{n}\right) + \log n$$

Renaming $m = \log n$ yields

> $$T(2^m) = 2T(2^{\frac{m}{2}}) + m$$

Renaming $S(m) = T(2^m)$ new recurrence becomes:

> $$S(m) = 2S\left(\frac{m}{2}\right) + m$$

How does this $T(2^{\frac{m}{2}})$ become $S\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you agree that $$S(m) = T(2^m)$$ 
now put $\frac{m}{2}$ inplace of $m$.

$$S(\frac{m}{2})=T(2^{\frac{m}{2}})$$
so what is $T(2^{\frac{m}{2}})$ now it is $S(\frac{m}{2})$
thus we can replace $T(2^{\frac{m}{2}})$ with $S(\frac{m}{2})$ right?
hope it clears your doubt!

Comment: Never thought it is going to be this easy : |